# Efficiently performing a bulk exact-match lookup in Lucene?

Tags: lucene

**tl;dr:**

What's the best way to bulk-fetch documents from Lucene using an exact-match on a set of keys?

---

**Long version:**

We have a Lucene index persisted to disk that is read through a `DirectoryReader`.

It contains 2,000,000 documents with the schema:

`{"key": "20-character-string", "value": "1-1000-character-string"}`

We now need to perform the equivalent of a `SELECT document WHERE document.key IN $keyArray` -- i.e. return the subset of documents whose keys intersect the `$keyArray` (a 10,000-item array of keys) using an exact-match.

Is there a better way than performing 10,000 separate searches?

Comment: I believe `TermInSetQuery` is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `TermInSetQuery`.

Under the hood it uses a sequence of `BooleanQuery` instances ORd together, if there are fewer than 16 terms in your set, else it uses something more efficient (presumably a hashset of sorts).